# How can I convert German characters during XML read and PHP write into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Morning,

I am inputting data from an XML file into my database, but have any isse with German words (that are in the XML by mistake)

For example the word für appears in my XML as fÃ¼r and thus appears the same in my database.

I know I could do a simple search/replace for that exact phrase, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do it as I can't predict if any other German words may one day appear in the XML?

ADDING SOME MORE DETAIL

The XML source says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

and in my PHP I have

> $domString =
>   utf8_encode($dom->saveXML($element));

If I look into the XML file before I start reading it, it has -

```
 <title> - <![CDATA[ CoPilot Live v8 Europa für Android 8.0.0.644 ]]> </title>
```

Thanks.

Greg

Comment: What the encoding of the XML file ? Do you generate it yourself ?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong encoding to read the xml, sounds like the source encoding is UTF-8 and you are reading iso-8859-1 or something like that

Comment: I think both are utf-8, I have added some detail to my origional question about this.

Answer (score 2):

This normally happens when UTF-8 data is deconded as ISO-8859-1 for example. In UTF-8 the german umlaut ü is represented by two bytes, in ISO-8859-1, it's one byte. the two bytes get decoded one by one resulting in an Ã and a ¼. Your task would be this:

- read the XML's bytes
- decode them using UTF-8

Check http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/ for byte values.

However, all in all, the idea of fixing this is pretty bad. You end up guessing encoding, not to talk about wrong encoded/decoded characters are encoded/decoded again... good luck!

EDIT:

I have used [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/), a library for guessing character encoding, in the meantime, and it seems to work fine. Maybe you give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

use the same encoding everywhere and there will be no such problems. and if you have to choose an encoding: use UTF-8!

if you can't change it (why ever...) you have to use [utf8_decode](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php) to get the correct values.

Comment: This is partially correct, but not the reason why this is happening. If you cannot change the encoding, then have to dig a bit deeper.. :)

Comment: I believe I am using UTF-8 everywhere, I've added some more detail to my question...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you are using DOMDocument then no matter what encoding your script is in, **it converts everything internally to UTF8**.

Also if you are using htmlentities, unless you specifically tell it to, it will use ISO-8859-1 encoding by default. Took me a while to figure this out!

Useful comment [here](http://usphp.com/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-save.php#67952), also from a german language perspective.

Answer (score 0):

For some things utf8_decode would work. 
You might want to have a look at his function as well: http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php#92592